# How can I suppress warning c4996 caused due to using deprecated methods of ODBC API

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

Full warning message is:

warning C4996: 'SQLSetConnectOption': ODBC API: SQLSetConnectOption is deprecated. Please use SQLSetConnectAttr instead.

Comment: Show the full error message including the bits preceding the string you show that are in square brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is to use #pragma warning(disable: 4996) around the call to SQLConnectOption:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

rc = SQLSetConnectOption(hdbc, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF);

#pragma warning(pop)
```

A more involved approach is to replace your calls to `SQLSetConnectOption` with equivalent calls to `SQLSetConnectAttr`.

There is a fairly detailed msdn article here [(MSDN Article on SQLSetConnectOption Mapping)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that explains how to convert the function call.  In most cases it appears fairly trivial; the first three arguments are identical, and the new 4th argument (StringLength) is either SQL_NTS if the value parameter is a string, 0 if it is an integer, or a length value if it is a driver-defined paramter.